# Linux LVM: Expanding vg to match "expanded" physical disk

Tags: lvm

I have a volume group that was created out of a 30Gb drive and a logical volume inside it with an ext3 filesystem.

Now the disk has magically "grown" another 30Gb to 60Gb (that is, I changed the physical device attached to the virtual machine...). Parted recognized the change and asked to fix itself (which I did).

How do I make the volume group expand (or "fix" itself) to match the new 60Gb drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think I got the answer on this one. Having come from HP-UX where LVM is native - and there are no partitions, I forgot something: on PC-based systems, LVM considers a partition to be a "physical device", not the entire disk as is natural in HP-UX LVM.

Thus, when the "disk" was expanded from 30Gb to 60Gb, the partition table tool (parted) saw it - and repaired the "damage" nicely.

However, the "physical disk" that LVM used never changed as the partition never changed size. The proper way to expand the filesystem involved was to:

1. Expand the volume group (using `vgextend`) to include the new partition.
2. Expand the logical volume (using `lvextend`) to encompass the rest of the
   space in the new volume group.
3. Expand the filesystem (in this case, by using `resize2fs`) to match the new space in
   the logical volume.

That did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than creating a new partition you could have also changed the partition size in the partition table to match the new size and then run `pvresize`.

Comment: Interesting! I think this is Linux-specific; there is a [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pvresize) for pvresize available online.

Comment: `# pvresize /dev/sdX; lvextend --resizefs -l +100%FREE /dev/my_vg_name/my_lv_name`